# How to instantiate a canvas in a dialog?

Tags: angularjs, dialog, material-design

I would like to instantiate a canvas available in a dialog but it always returns a null object. In my JavaScript file I have :

```
     $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
        var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs'))  && $scope.customFullscreen;
        var myDialog = $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            templateUrl: '../templates/dialogCanvas.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            fullscreen: useFullScreen,
        })
                .then(function(answer) {
                    $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
        }, function() {
            $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            return $mdMedia('xs') || $mdMedia('sm');
        }, function(wantsFullScreen) {
            $scope.customFullscreen = (wantsFullScreen === true);
        });
    };
```

In my HTML file (dialogCanvas.html), I have this tag :

```
<div id="back">
    <canvas id="canvasZone"></canvas>
</div>
```

And finally in the controller function I try to instantiate the canvas by doing this :

```
    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasZone');
    }
```

But the object is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try get the canvas object using `$timeout` or `$evalAsync`.In this way the function inside will get executed after DOM manipulating.

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasZone');
});
```

or

```
$timeout(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasZone');
},0);
```